# Python. Generate imitation of sentence from random letters from large text

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a total newbie. I'm writing a code for my python classes and I'm looking for help.
This is supposed to be a code imitating language, in this case latin.
I want to take random letter from long string.
When I have letter1, I'd like to find all indexes of the same letter in the text. Then randomly take one index and take +1 to pick the next letter.
And I want to keep adding letters in this way until it will generate '.' end of sentence.
I have two first letters and I'm stuck. The third letter should be connected with second etc. Don't know, how to generate the next letters, maybe in a while loop.

```
import random

text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan, dolor eu maximus vulputate. Urna tortor vestibulum justo. Et fermentum libero tellus quis diam. Aenean massa nisi.'
while True:
    letter = random.choice(text)
    print(letter, end='')
    indexes3 = [i for i,x in enumerate(text) if x == letter]
    nextindex = random.choice(indexes3)+1
    print(text[nextindex], end='')
    if letter == '.':
        break
```

I'd be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You pick a letter randomly from the whole string only the first time, so this should be before the loop. Then you pick one of the succeeding letters. Now reset `letter` to the picked one and repeat the process:

```
import random

text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan, dolor eu maximus vulputate. Urna tortor vestibulum justo. Et fermentum libero tellus quis diam. Aenean massa nisi.'

letter = random.choice(text)
while letter != '.':
    print(letter, end='')
    indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(text) if x == letter]
    next_index = random.choice(indexes) + 1
    letter = text[next_index]

print(letter) # to print a dot and a newline
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.
Gratias vobis!!